# Subset nested list to only include element named in a vector

Tags: r, list, subset, lapply

i have a nested list :

```
myList <- list(info = "list", 
               elements = list("element 1" = list(cost = 7, distance = 11, quality = 3),
                               "element 2" = list(cost = 7, distance = 13, quality = 3),
                               "element 3" = list(cost = 22, distance = 11, quality = 9)))
```

from this list i want to keep only some elements. Those elements that should be kept are stored in a vector called `toBeSubset`

```
toBeSubset <- c("element 1", "element 3")
```

i stated with:

```
names(myList$elements) %in% toBeSubset
```

but i am stuck here. Any tips?

desired output:

```
myListSubset <- list(info = "list", 
               elements = list("element 1" = list(cost = 7, distance = 11, quality = 3),
                               "element 3" = list(cost = 22, distance = 11, quality = 9)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
c(myList[1], myList$elements[names(myList$elements) %in% toBeSubset])

#$info
#[1] "list"

#$`element 1`
#$`element 1`$cost
#[1] 7

#$`element 1`$distance
#[1] 11

#$`element 1`$quality
#[1] 3


#$`element 3`
#$`element 3`$cost
#[1] 22

#$`element 3`$distance
#[1] 11

#$`element 3`$quality
#[1] 9
```

Comment: that looks great. However info = "list" is missing

Comment: Updated the answer @Nneka to include info = 'list' information.

Answer (score 2):

We could also do

```
c(myList[1], myList[["elements"]][names(myList[["elements"]]) %in% toBeSubset])
```